Body on an inclined plane (excercise)
A body slides along an inclined plane from bottom to top with an initial speed of 2 m/s. Having risen to some height, it slides along the same path back. What is the speed of the body when it returns to the starting point? Friction coefficient 0.4, plane inclination angle 30°. Expected answer[0.84 m/s].
[edit] I understand that body has kinetic energy mv^2/2, but due to friction and gravitational pull working against it it will stop, but i don't understand how exactly it affects kinetic energy.

they won't do your homework here, maybe you should list a few formulas and ask how to use them .....

If there is some concept you are not clear about, ask about it.
